# How to map excel column name with database column name using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do mapping of excel column name with database column name. I want, when i upload excel, then show excel column names and database column name to map cause of assign the column. If our excel column is different from database column then we can assign excel column with database column and then we can use it to insert the excel data into database based on assigning columns.

The excel file is uploading well but i don't know how to map excel column name with database column name. Please help to solve this, I am new in .net C#.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            String path = Server.MapPath("~/upload/");
            String fullPath = path + FileUpload1.FileName;
            string connString = "";
            string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fullPath);
            string Excel = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            //Connection String to Excel Workbook
            if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;Persist Security Info = False;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes; Persist Security Info = False;IMEX=2\"";
            }

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastNamefrom [Sheet1$]", conn);

            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string Title = dr[0].ToString();
                string FirstName = dr[1].ToString();
                string MiddleName = dr[2].ToString();
                string LastName = dr[3].ToString();

                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString2"].ConnectionString);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();

                    cmd2.Connection = con;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd2.CommandText = "procedure";                   
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Title);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : FirstName);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(MiddleName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : MiddleName);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : LastName);

                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    msg.Text = "<span style='color:Green'>Data Has Been Saved Successfully.</div>";
                    con.Close();
                }

            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            File.Delete(fullPath);
        }
```

I am using this code to insert the data into database. But i do not not how to do mapping of excel column and database column.

Comment: How do you upload the Excel file to the database? How is the mapping currently orginised? Since you are looking for a C# answer, show us the code you are currently using.

Comment: @GvS Please check. i add insertion code, but dont know how to map the column. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: I dont know if i understand you correct. Do you want to insert the data from an excelfile into the database?

Comment: Yes, i want to insert but first i want to map excel column with database column. Because whenever excel column name is different from database then data will save in database based on assigned column. I know how to insert data into database but no any idea to map excel column with database column name. Hope now u understand?

Comment: Depending on many extra columns are there in the sheet, and if the order is fixed, you could use `Select *`. Also depends on the source of the file. If the file generated by software, the format will be fixed. If it is edited by humans, the format will be different and cannot be trusted.

Comment: You have any idea to get column name of excel?

Comment: Why is the name of the excel column important, if it can change? How will knowing the name of column help you selecting the right column in the database?